# How to add subviews to a custom UITableViewCell in a storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, storyboard

In Xcode 4, you used to be able to add subviews to the contentView of a dynamic UITableViewCell prototype in a storyboard. I no longer seem to be able to do this--when I drag any view to the table view cell, it doesn't let me add it to the cell, only to the parent table view. Is there a new way to do this that I don't know about yet?

[image: storyboard]

[image: view hierarchy]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's still possible in Xcode 5.

I think the reason why you can't is that you are missing the contentView for your cell. It might be that you either accidentally deleted it or the XIB or Storyboard somehow got corrupted.

Normally, your table view controller hierarchy should look like the one below. You would then add your subviews to the contentView.

If it was me and your still this early in development, I would just recreate it, or otherwise split the cells out into their own XIBs (which also has the nice side effect of making them reusable in other view controllers)

[image]

Comment: The issue in my case was that I was increasing the number of prototype cells by changing the number in the table view properties inspector rather than dragging in a table view cell from the object library.

Answer (score 12):

It's Xcode 5 bug.

Cell created without Content View.
In my case I added one more prototype cell and remove previous, in new cell content view is present.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 5 storyboard, if you add a **Prototype cell** by selecting your **UITableView** and clicking on **Prototype Cells count option in Attribute Inspector**, then for the first time the **Prototype cell** will be created without **Content View**.

The solution for this problem is either you **create two Prototype Cells** and delete the first one **or** drag and drop Table View Cell from Object Library in to your UITableView. In both cases you will have **TableViewCell** with a **Content View**.

Answer (score 0):

My `UITableViewCell` appeared **with** a `contentView` and I still couldn't connect the `IBOutlets` to the subviews. I ended up deleting the parent `UITableView`, the `UITableViewCell` Prototype, and all related subviews. I then re-added everything back in and the `IBOutlet`-connection dragging magically works. I think it's an Xcode bug stemming from copy-pasting a controller and/or subviews into a storyboard and/or adding the prototyped cells manually in the inspector.

Comment: It seems to me that you failed to subclass the UITableViewCell