# Using a Custom UITableViewCell with Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For reference, this tutorial I am following: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

I have to create a custom UITableViewCell, and from the tutorial, it said to leverage Prototyping cells and subclass UITableViewCell. Then connect the UI elements in the prototype cel to the custom class (of UITableViewCell).

The problem I am running into here is, there is only one cell for the whole table view that is displaying data. However, I am able to click on empty cells in the background behind that one cell that contains data. If i scroll up or down, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called and another cell gets displayed. However its only displaying once cell at a time for the whole table view.

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem could be here? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What does your tableview delegate code look like?

Comment: Thanks for the response valheru, finally figured out the problem though. My label was added to the parent table view and not the table view cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what the problem is, my labels (that are supposed to be inside the custom prototyping cell) were added to the parent view and not the content view of UITableViewCell. This is because my prototype cell did not have a content view for some reason. I had to add a another prototype cell and delete the previous one.

reference: [How to add subviews to a custom UITableViewCell in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434804/how-to-add-subviews-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-a-storyboard)